# remove user from the "all" mailing-list

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2003, outlook-2007

I am running Windows Server 2003 with exchange 2003.
Outlook provides an "all" mailing list option.
So if you write "all" in the `To:`field, everybody at the office receives the e-mail.

I need to make sure this certain user, does not receive these global emails.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What is your mail server?

Comment: Ah, good question. It is Exchange server 2003. I will add the info right away

Answer (score 2):

When you send to "All" you are sending email to everyone in the global address list. You can hide a user from the GAL by doing the following:

- From Active Directory Users and Computers
- Go to View and make sure Advanced Features is checked
- Now find the user that you want to hide from the address list and select properties
- Click on the Exchange Advanced tab
- Check "Hide from Exchange Address lists"
- Click OK

This will hide the user in the GAL, it will however stop the user showing up in the address Global Address List when users are looking at it to send them a mail, which i'm not sure if it what you want.

If you want the user to still appear in the GAL for lookups, but not recieve mail sent to the GAL, then you have a bit of a problem, as they are kind of contradictory.

Comment: I'll have to look into this, before I accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using Distribution Groups in AD.  Add everyone except that user to a distribution group and retrain users to use that global group when they want to exclude that one user.